# Hello, i use NextJs and i need to achieve url like page/[id]/[slug] from page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I need to take the data as I had on the/[id] page, but in the URL I want to have the/[id]/[slug] page. Can I do this, and if I can, how?

Comment: Can you give a practical example of your case to understand it better? I assume you've read the docs here - https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 0):

Make another `[slug]` folder inside `[id]` folder.

So your file structure should be like this

```
|- pages
|-- [id]
|--- [slug] 
|---- index.js
```

Then you can direct your page like this:

```
<Link href="/post/MY-ID-VALUE/MY-SLUG">
    <a>Go to pages/post/[id]/[slug].js</a>
 </Link>
```

Then in your `/pages/[id]/[slug]/index.js` you can get back the value of `id` and `slug` like this:

```
const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id, slug } = router.query

  return <p>MyId is: {id} Slug: {slug}</p>
}
```